# Assigning certain authors to specific editors

Tags: user-roles, user-access

I have two editors(A and B), two authors(C and D).
I want to assign author(C) to editor(A), and author(D) to editor(B).

So that the posts created by author(C) only editor(A) can view and
posts created by author(D) only editor(B) can view.
Also the posts created by editor(A) should not be visible to editor(B) and vice versa.

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?
Please help..I Need to solve this urgently.

Comment: [User Role Editor](https://www.role-editor.com/) is a plugin that designed for this purpose. Check this [page](https://www.role-editor.com/allow-user-edit-selected-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

This I have achieved without using any plugin.
In admin I created custom field to fetch all the authors in the multiselect box. Here the editor can select as many author he wants.
[image]

Then I added function in function.php file to fetch all the posts created by the current editor user and also by the author who falls under his category

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpcf_filter_author_posts' );
function wpcf_filter_author_posts( $query ){
    global $post_type, $pagenow;
    //if we are currently on the edit screen of the post type listings
    if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'videos' && current_user_can('editor')){
        global $user_ID;
        $meta = get_user_meta( $user_ID );
        $selected_author_id = unserialize($meta['select_md'][0]);
        if(isset($selected_author_id) && !empty($selected_author_id)){
            $count = count($selected_author_id);
            $selected_author_id[$count] = $user_ID;
            $query->query_vars['author__in'] = $selected_author_id;
        } else {
            $query->query_vars['author'] = $user_ID;

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my post listing screen
[image]

Here the author is Client3 and Promoter 1 is editor

Comment: sounds like a great idea
but how did you create the custom field to fetch all the authors?